# Adding a UINavigationController to an existing UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

simple question... My app starts out with a UINavigationController with a UIViewController (of course), but when a button is pressed, I want another UINavigationController to be presented.

Would I do:

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:AnotherNavigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

or:

```
[self presentViewController:AnotherNavigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Both ways work... But I'm not sure which one is correct... And also, I can't seem to get the BarButtonItem's to appear once that navigationcontroller is presented

PS. The navigationcontroller has a tabbarcontroller with two tab views in it

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:AnotherNavigationController animated:YES];
```

Use push segue instead.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with push segue
PS. Thanks for fast response!

Comment: Also, pushViewController will not work because it says: Pushing a navigation controller is not supported... Which is why I'm using presentViewController

Comment: Why do you want to present a navigation controller?

Comment: Well maybe you can give me an alternative. I originally used a toolbar, should I just stick with that? I basically have the start of the app going to a Login View (which is in a navigationbarcontroller) and then when you login, it will present a tabbarcontroller with two views (each in a tab)
So , I need to have some navigation on top, should I just use a toolbar? or is there a way to get a navigation on top of both views with the navigation bar controller?

Comment: Can you send a picture of your storyboard.

Comment: I'm not using a storyboard, I prefer not to use them. Thank you for the help, I decided to just stick with the toolbar. But if you are able to help me with other things, I am trying to create a User class so I can log in and out of the app; What is the best way to do so (and I think I would need it to be singleton so I can store information)

Comment: I can't help you here ask a separate question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34502/discussion-between-d34thst4lker-and-abdullah-shafique)

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

after login sucess

```
UIStoryboard  *Story_TabController = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil]
 UIViewController *class1 = [Story_TabController instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Feed_ViewController"];

   UIViewController *class = [Story_TabController instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FindFriends_ViewController"];


   UINavigationController *nav_profile=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:class1];
   UINavigationController *nav_post=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:class2];

    Tab_controller.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:nav_profile,nav_post, nil];

    Tab_controller.selectedIndex=0;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:Tab_controller animated:YES];
```